# How can I use these logical equivalences to rewrite this sentence?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Here are the logical equivalences:

1. $p \rightarrow q \vee r$
2. $p \wedge \lnot q \rightarrow r$
3. $p \wedge \lnot r \rightarrow q$

Sentence:

If $c$ is prime, then $c$ is odd or $c$ is $2$.

How can I rewrite the above sentence using the logical equivalences in 2 different ways?

Comment: What have you tried? Hint: $p \rightarrow q$ ~ "if $p$, then $q$", $p \wedge q$ ~ "$p$ and $q$", $p \vee q$ ~ "$p$ or $q$".

Comment: 2. If c is prime and c is not odd, then c is 2.

Comment: 3. If c is prime and c is not 2, then c is odd.

Comment: @cbo1: Looks fine!

Answer (score 0):

If $c$ is prime, then $c$ is odd or $c$ is $2$.

1. p = c is prime
2. q= c is odd or c is 2
3. a= c is odd
4. b=c is 2

then we have :

$$p→(a∨b)$$

this logic only in one state is $0$ just when $p=1$ and $a,b=0(a∨b = 0)$.